# Filtering duplicate img src with jQuery unique or remove

Tags: jquery, image, unique

I've tried different workarounds that have been discussed here, but none of them are working in my case.

This is my source:

```
<div class="colourDots">
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.sw.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
```

I would like to show only unique "img src" of the above list, no duplicated pictures ...

Script:

```
var uniqueImg = $(".colourDots img").get();
divs = $.unique(uniqueImg);
```

I'm getting the same source again :-(

Any ideas or any other workarounds?

Comment: BTW, the reason this isn't working is because the `unique()` function is checking for the duplication of the *actual* DOM element in the jQuery object, not the duplication of an elements property. If you did `$(this).add(this).add(this).add(this).unique().length`, you'll get `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var srcs = [],
        temp;
    $(".colourDots img").filter(function(){
        temp = $(this).attr("src");
        if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
            srcs.push(temp);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).remove();
});
```

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/xCjjp/

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
$(".colourDots img").​​​​​​​​each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().length)
        $(".colourDots img:contains('" + $(this).jpg() + "')").not(this).remove();
});​
```

See http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/

Comment: can you explain me why you are attach function to `anchor tag` ?

Comment: i said "a" but meant "img" See: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/ for more info. I copied my own sample and replaced the .jpg but that wasn't enough

Comment: I assume it's supposed to be `$(this).attr('src')`

Comment: hmmm, thanks for quickest support ever ;-) ... i'm still getting some errors but i will try it with .each ...

Answer (score 0):

what i'll do is, first get all those image tag's `src` attr into an array

```
var img_array = $(".colourDots img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
});
```

Now here i can do duplicate check process within this array and remove all the img whose src is found more than once in this array, here all img are removed so i'll add back one single image of src.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version I put together from all answers:

```
var img_array = $(".colourDots img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
});
img_array = $.unique(img_array);
img_array.each(function(index, value){
    var sel = '.colourDots img[src="' + value+ '"]';
    $(sel).not($(sel + ':first')).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZWY5/3/

Comment: also, working fine in the same way !! ... even in Internet Explorer ;-)