# Wordpress Jquery Colorbox remove duplicates

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I have this wordpress e-commerce site here /products-page/rings/product-1-2/ and I am using a plugin called jquery-colorbox and as you can see from the page link I have 4 images, 2 are the same, you when click on any of the images it says the gallery has 3 images (which is true) but 1 of them is a duplicate. Is there away to remove duplicates from jquery-colorbox? I have tried to google for it and found nothing :(

If anyone can put me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code, if it helps

```
<div class="imagecol">
<a class="preview_link cboxElement" style="text-decoration:none;" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring">
<img id="product_image_736" class="product_image colorbox-736" width="400" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" title="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" alt="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring">
<br>
<div style="text-align:center; color:#F39B91;">Click To Enlarge</div>
</a>
<div class="wpcart_gallery" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="DSC_0118" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="DSC_0118" alt="DSC_0118" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118-50x50.jpg">
</a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="P7230376" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="P7230376" alt="P7230376" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376-50x50.jpg">
</a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="P7230378" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="P7230378" alt="P7230378" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378-50x50.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I added this to my `<head></head>` section

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var srcs = [],
            temp;
        $(".attachment-gold-thumbnails img").filter(function(){
            temp = $(this).attr("src");
            if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
                srcs.push(temp);   
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).remove();
    });

    </script>
```

and it still didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Code copied, but here it is none the less:

```
$(function(){
    var srcs = [],
        temp;
    $(".attachment-gold-thumbnails img").filter(function(){
        temp = $(this).attr("src");
        if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
            srcs.push(temp);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).remove();
});
```

Check [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415910/filtering-duplicate-img-src-with-jquery-unique-or-remove) for details:

Comment: I applied your code...I placed it just below the wpcart_gallery div class and it didnt work :( Am I placing it in the wrong place?

Comment: Apply in <head><script> $(document).ready(function() {));</script></head>.

Comment: I updated my code to show you what I did and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: it does not work when I apply it to the site, I looked at your code and i think its not what I am looking for...its seems to me that the big image is the placeholder, if you click on any of the images below it replaces the big image with that one, and for the color-box to open you have to click on the big image.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this using this jQuery code:

```
var arrayImgsColorbox = new Array();

$('.cboxElement').each(function(i, obj){
    if($.inArray($(obj).attr('href'), arrayImgsColorbox ) > -1)
        $(obj).removeClass('cboxElement');
    else
        arrayImgsColorbox[i] = $(obj).attr('href');
});
```