# jquery remove duplicate images

Tags: php, jquery, duplicates

I am trying to find a quick easy way of removing duplicate images on a page with jQuery.

I have an array of images getting pulled in, and the majority are duplicated or have the same url.

I have tried the solution here: [Filtering duplicate img src with jQuery unique or remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415910/filtering-duplicate-img-src-with-jquery-unique-or-remove), but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone done something similar before?

PHP:

```
public function getWeeklyTrackChartGrid($methodVars) {
    // Check for required variables
    if ( !empty($methodVars['group']) ) {
        $vars = array(
            'method' => 'group.getweeklytrackchart',
            'api_key' => $this->auth->apiKey
        );
        $vars = array_merge($vars, $methodVars);

        if ( $call = $this->apiGetCall($vars) ) {
            $i = 0;


            $loopN = $call->weeklytrackchart->track;


            foreach ($loopN as $track ) {

                require 'config.php';
                 //if(++$i > $userLimit*2) break;


                 $albumArtS = $tracks['album']['image']['small'] = (string) $track->image[0];
                 $albumArtM = $tracks['album']['image']['small'] = (string) $track->image[1];
                 $albumArtL = $tracks['album']['image']['small'] = (string) $track->image[2];

                 $playCounts = $tracks[$i]['playcount'] = (string) $track->playcount; 

                 ?>


                   <?php if ($playCounts > 1)  { ?>

                   <?php if ($albumArtL)  { ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $albumArtL; ?>" />

                        <?php } ?>

                   <?php } else { ?>

                   <?php if ($albumArtM)  { ?> 

                        <img src="<?php echo $albumArtM; ?>" />

                        <?php } ?>

                   <?php } ?>


                 <?php if ($albumArtwork == "yes")  { ?>


                    <?php if ($albumArt)  { ?>


                    <?php } }?>



            <?php   $i++;
            }
            return $tracks;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Give a 91 error if incorrect variables are used
        $this->handleError(91, 'You must include a group variable in the call for this method');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var srcs = [],
        temp;
    $("img").filter(function(){
        temp = $(this).attr("src");
        if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
            srcs.push(temp);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: what does that code have to do with jQuery? Thats PHP

Comment: i no it's php, but i would like to remove with jQuery

Comment: So, um, please show us what you've tried with jQuery.  After all, you said you tried something and it didn't work.

Comment: i have added the jQuery to the above code

Comment: your answer is what i originally posted, and didn't work for me. I appreciate your answer, but I posted my solution which works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
var img_array = $("#singleTracks img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
});
img_array = $.unique(img_array);
img_array.each(function(index, value){
    var sel = '#singleTracks img[src="' + value+ '"]';
    var imgs = $(sel).not($(sel + ':first'));
    imgs.remove();
});
```